# alter table in multiple database postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, shell, alter-table

I have multiple database, each has table "authentication". In each table I want to drop a constraint and replace it with a new one. That would be great if I had not to do that manually.

```
ALTER TABLE authentication DROP CONSTRAINT  uk_authentication_01;
ALTER TABLE authentication ADD CONSTRAINT uk_authentication_01 UNIQUE (authenticator, method);
```

is there a way to do a bulk alter with a script?

Comment: You can do that with `dblink` and database list from `pg_database`.

Comment: hi, I have the list of databases, however the whole thing is not really clear to me. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-function.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over your databases in a shell script:

```
for db in dbname1 dbname2 dbname3...
do
 psql -d $db -U username << EOF
ALTER TABLE authentication DROP CONSTRAINT  uk_authentication_01;
ALTER TABLE authentication ADD CONSTRAINT uk_authentication_01 UNIQUE (authenticator, method);
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all databases are on the same server?
If that is true you can simply do the SELECT:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM  dblink_exec(''dbname=' || datname 
         || '''::text, ''ALTER TABLE authentication 
         DROP CONSTRAINT  uk_authentication_01;
         ALTER TABLE authentication ADD CONSTRAINT uk_authentication_01 
         UNIQUE (authenticator, method);''::text);'
FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

Then copy the result of this query and run it.

And you'll need for that dblink extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Comment: yes, they are on the same servlet. Let me try it out, if works I'll be back to accept as the right answer.

Comment: Sadly, it does not seem to be working. Can we stick to the bare essentials? Let's say I just want to drop the first constraint and I want to perform it on only two databases baml1 and baml2. Those are on the same server.

Comment: Have you installed the extension first?

Comment: When you run just - SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false; Do you get the list of dbs?

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pkg/share/postgresql/extension/dblink.control": No such file or directory

Comment: so you need to install the sources of dblink first and it's gonna run fine: http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/first-steps-with-dblink-on-postgres/